# Angular2 merge part of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to merge two same type observables and return same type observable in Angular2 function.
So all I want to do is:

from this:

```
obs1.subscribe(obs => console.log(obs))
(where I get): 
{
   count: 10,
   array: <someObservable[]> 
}
```

and

```
obs2.subscribe(obs => console.log(obs))
(where I get): 
{
   count: 10,
   array: <someObservable[]> (different objects)
}
```

into:

```
{
   count: 10 (count always the same number),
   array: <someObservable[]> (combined array from obs1 and obs2)
}
```

What is the simplest way to achieve that?
(Maybe it is simple to even junior level angular developer, but I have to it quickly and Im newbie in this sphere).
Thanks in advice.

---**UPDATE**---

from this code part :

```
const obs2 = obs1.pipe(
        switchMap(value => {
          return this._loadMoreTextSearchSub.asObservable()
          .pipe(pairwise(),
          map(params => this.getPagingParameters(params[0], params[1])),
          switchMap(request),
          map(response => response.packages),
          scan<SearchPackage[]>((all, current) => {
            return [...all, ...current];
          }, 
          value.packages
          ));
        }))
        .subscribe(data => console.log('sec', data));
```

I get array of objects.
How could I wrap that array into the object and set extra property - 'count'?

```
Current:
[{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
Desired:
{count: some_number, array: [{...}, {...}, {...}]}
```

Comment: It depends on how do you want to call the observables, should they be called subsequently, parallely?

Comment: They called subsequently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to call the Observables subsequently then you can use `mergeMap()` for the same.

Lets say, you call `obs1` first, once you have the result of `obs1`, you call `obs2`, then  combine both the results and return.

```
obs1.pipe(mergeMap((firstResult) => {
    return obs2.pipe(map((secondResult) => {
        return { count: firstResult.count, array: [...firstResult.array, ...secondResult.array] };
    }))

})).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Appreciate your help!
Is it hard to rewrite code for parallely called observations?

Comment: @Karlito Nope, its all the same. You have `forkJoin()`, `combineLatest()`, `withLatestFrom()`, `zip()`, etc. You can use any of them, depending on your requirement. Just the ways of using them are different.

Comment: @Karlito See this link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom .Its very nicely explained for some of them'.